# How to compare mongoDB ObjectIds & remove duplicates in an array of documents using node.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose-schema

I have an array called "doc" which contains a list, in which some of them contains same ref object id, I have to remove that duplicate, but none of the code is working because I'm filtering according to ref object id, which is in the form of object. I have to access the id inside the object and filter it according to that object id. here userId is the referance object id.

```
Answer.find({'blockId': questId}, (err, doc) => {
        if(doc!=null){
            userId = 0;
            userList = [];
            userIdd = 0;
            uslist = [];
            for(var i = 0; i<doc.length; i++){
                if(userId != doc[i].userId){
                    userIdList.push({'userId':doc[i].userId});
                    userId = doc[i].userId;
                }
            }
        }else{

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a simple solution for this.
if 'doc' is the array which contains duplicates.

```
 userIdList = [];
 userIdList = Object.values(doc.reduce((acc,cur)=>Object.assign(acc,{[cur.userId.toString()]:cur}),{}));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting `doc[i].userId` field values as `ObjectId()`'s from DB, then try this :

```
Answer.find({ 'blockId': questId }, (err, doc) => {
    if (err) {
        // return here itself
    }
    let userId = '';
    let userIdList = [];
    if (doc.length) {
        for (var i = 0; i < doc.length; i++) {
            /** Since we're using mongoose use `.toHexString()` to convert to string & compare,
               if you're using mongoDB driver use `toString()` to convert to string */.
            if (userId != (doc[i].userId).toHexString()) {
                userIdList.push({ 'userId': doc[i].userId });
                userId = (doc[i].userId).toHexString();
            }
        }
    } else {
       console.log('No matching answers found for blockId ::', questId)
    }
})
```

Above code should work via `Node.Js`, just in case if your intention is all about just to get unique `userId`'s try this as it helps to achieve things in DB itself in quick :

```
Answer.aggregate({$match : {"blockId" : 1}},
{$group : {_id : {blockId: '$blockId'},userIds: {$addToSet : '$userId'} }}).lean(true).exec((err, doc)=> {})
```

**Collection Data :**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e103f0b400289966e01dc47"),
    "blockId" : 1,
    "userId" : ObjectId("5dfeac7b400289966e2042c7")
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e103f34400289966e01e1f9"),
    "blockId" : 1,
    "userId" : ObjectId("5dfeac7b400289966e2042c5")
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e103f4a400289966e01e56c"),
    "blockId" : 1,
    "userId" : ObjectId("5dfeac7b400289966e2042c7")
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e103f51400289966e01e678"),
    "blockId" : 1,
    "userId" : ObjectId("5dfeac7b400289966e2042c6")
}

/* 5 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e103f57400289966e01e793"),
    "blockId" : 1,
    "userId" : ObjectId("5dfeac7b400289966e2042c1")
}

/* 6 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e103f61400289966e01e92b"),
    "blockId" : 2,
    "userId" : ObjectId("5dfeac7b400289966e2042c9")
}

/* 7 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e1040c3400289966e021168"),
    "blockId" : 1,
    "userId" : ObjectId("5dfeac7b400289966e2042c5")
}
```

**Result :**

```
/* 1 */
/** Duplicates removed */
{
    "_id" : {
        "blockId" : 1
    },
    "userIds" : [ 
        ObjectId("5dfeac7b400289966e2042c1"), 
        ObjectId("5dfeac7b400289966e2042c6"), 
        ObjectId("5dfeac7b400289966e2042c5"), 
        ObjectId("5dfeac7b400289966e2042c7")
    ]
}
```

Or if you just wanted to use `.find()` & still do it in `node.js`, again if your operation is all about unique userId's, then at-least add projection to your code in order to retrieve only needed fields from DB :

```
Answer.find({ 'blockId': questId }, {_id :0, 'blockId':1, userId:1 }, (err, doc) => { })
```